# How can I add a large number of static HTML files to rails app without slowing the development cycle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am wondering the best way to include an old web site into a newer rails app.

The legacy web site:

- Has 21,000 small text files with minimal markup that are linked together.
- Totals ~ 220MB
- Has a root page located within a directory and is linked to many sub-directories

I'd like to include the old site in my rails app folder, but I am concerned that it will mean a much longer development cycle each time I deploy.  I am using capistrano and my first thought is to place the folder with **Old Site** in the shared directory on the production server and symbolically link to it accordingly.  This approach strikes me as undesirable as my resources for **New App** will be split in more than one location.  The benefit might be a much quicker debug/deploy cycle.

Right now, I have no plans to modify the **Old Site** files.  At some point, that could change.

I have been impressed with how quickly my otherwise lightweight project will deploy.  Right now I am making frequent changes and repeating the code/deploy cycle often.  I'd like to avoid slowing that down unnecessarily.

Is there a best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be worried about this slowing down your development cycle. You can add as much static data as you like to your Rails app and its Git repository, and there is no penalty or slowdown.

Comment: Not to be coy, but is this true?  Deployment now happens in about 25 sec. Would adding 21,000 text files not impact that metric?

Comment: Deployment and development are two completely different things. Your development environment is not affected by static files on disk. Your deployment process *may* be, if you are copying all of those files across the network on each deploy.

Comment: I deployed this app a few days ago and have been working through the kinks of deployment.  It all feels like development, but I see you are right about making the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "*best practice*" per se, but one option would be to use "[Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)". Add your **Old Site** as a submodule in the right folder in your **New Site** and you have one developer git repository and Capistrano will not fetch git submodule files while deploying.

With submodules, you will have 2 git repositories. But, one will be linked from within another one ("old site" in "new site"). I think, it is logical. You will have old site repo and new site repo. They are 2 separate sites after all, just linked.

Comment: Will take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: This does look like a viable option.  Thanks.  I have come to appreciate git quite a bit, but my comfort level as a git user remains pretty low.  Not so much for workflow that is going fine, but when things go wrong, I stress that I will misstep with git.